# PHP - trying to get google image html with curl but result is different than in browser

Tags: php, regex, curl

I'm learning regex, php & cUrl and would like to get Google Image html 
(for example : https://www.google.fr/search?q=terrorist&biw=1920&bih=1008&source=lnms&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch&q=love)
I tried a lot of different answers but I don't understand why, surprisingly, when I do

```
<?php
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($conn2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$get_page = curl_get_contents("https://www.google.fr/search?q=terrorist&biw=1920&bih=1008&source=lnms&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch&q=love");
echo $get_page;
   ?>
```

I've got a very different result than in browser. All images links are dead for example.
Does anyone know why ? And what could I do to fix it?
Thanx a lot !!

Comment: the result page from google search can be / is different by every client .. so when you open it on "your" browser you can get (or get) another match list as open it on "server" by curl ... thats google

Comment: maybe try an well known user agent string by setting CURLOPT_USERAGENT

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I tried to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');

Comment: The Google pages usually contain a lot of scripts that do all the magic you see in browser.

Comment: but I still can't get any imgurl in the result, or I can in the source in the browser :/

Comment: @axiac so you think that is not possible to retrieve the images urls directly with PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 search queries in this request as shown below

https://www.google.fr/search?**q=terrorist**&biw=1920&bih=1008&source=lnms&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch&**q=love**

try

https://www.google.fr/search?q=love&biw=1920&bih=1008&source=lnms&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch

It looks like its returning the first query in the browser and then running the second, but it wont do the second request via curl.

This works for me:

```
<?php
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
$get_page = curl_get_contents("https://www.google.fr/search?q=love&biw=1920&bih=1008&source=lnms&tbm=isch&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=isch");
echo $get_page;
?>
```

EDIT: After further research this is an unsupported way of doing this, You should be using [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview). The way that you are doing it will result in Google detecting misuse and presenting you with Captcha requests or maybe even blocking you.

Comment: Thanks I just saw it(https://www.google.fr/search?q=love&source=lnms&tbm=isch) But it doesn't change the result. I still get a simpler html page...

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I am using and it returns a results page as expected (and a var_dump I put in for testing)

Comment: When you check the source, the first jpg you can find gives that: <a href="http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http://quotesnsmiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/LoveQuotes.jpg&amp;imgrefurl=http://www.wdyl.com/%23love&amp;h=1920&amp;w=2560&amp;tbnid=41NNjsCsEIh_-M:&amp;zoom=1&amp;docid=iFLD-cnOZI3n6M&amp;ei=KPmrVKSOH4v-UPOjhLgL&amp;tbm=isch" jsaction="str.hc;mousedown:str.hmd;mouseover:str.hmov;mouseout:str.hmou" class="rg_l" data-ved="0CCkQrQMwAA">

Comment: but in my curl result, the first jpg gives that: <a href="/url?q=http://www.wdyl.com/%23love&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=z_mrVNqhL4SR7AbO14CIDw&amp;ved=0CBYQ9QEwAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNF-uFEVkjjW5HSg6abXU2h9UsSvuw"> .... very strange

Comment: You would probably be better off using [Google's Search API's](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! But for me it doesn't. When I click on the first image result, it doesn't link anywhere : the image url source is missing..

Comment: Google use relative urls for the images such as `/url?q=http://www.breastcancerwellness.org/%3Fattachment_id%3D7603&sa=U&ei=u_urVOSNB8u2UabXg7AL&ved=0CBYQ9QEwAA&usg=AFQjCNH4JJ8-mlQq6vYL4zRG4CJweCQt4w` This is so that can track clicks, prevent people linking directly to them and also show previews. This is why you should use their API's or parse the URL's in your code and remove the `/url?q=` part

Comment: Maybe but there are limitations about that, I think. The app I would like to create does a hundred of different requests each time it is showed, and it would be showed several times by day. And even parsed, this image url (www.breastcancer...) does not lead to any jpg file. But thanks for your help!

Comment: You should be using [this](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) to retrieve Google image search results. That's the officially supported way to do what you want. If you make too many requests to google search without using the API's they will present you with Captcha requests and even block you